# The constraint reference 'slugify' could not be resolved to a type

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-2.2

ASP.NET Core 2.2 has introduced an option for slugifying routing url using [Parameter transformer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#parameter-transformer-reference) as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home:slugify}/{action=Index:slugify}/{id?}");
```

I have done the same thing as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller:slugify}/{action:slugify}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

My routing configuration in the `ConfigureServices` method as follows:

```
services.AddRouting(option =>
            {
                option.LowercaseUrls = true;
            });
```

but getting the following errors:

> InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'slugify' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.

and

> RouteCreationException: An error occurred while creating the route with name 'default' and template '{controller:slugify}/{action:slugify}/{id?}'.

May be I am missing anything more! Any help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ASP.NET Core [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#parameter-transformer-reference) says I have to configure `Parameter transformer` using [ConstraintMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routeoptions.constraintmap?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_RouteOptions_ConstraintMap). So I have done as follows and it works:

Routing configuration in the `ConfigureServices` method should be as follows:

```
services.AddRouting(option =>
            {
                option.ConstraintMap["slugify"] = typeof(SlugifyParameterTransformer);
                option.LowercaseUrls = true;
            });
```

Then the `SlugifyParameterTransformer` as follows:

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
    {
        public string TransformOutbound(object value)
        {
            // Slugify value
            return value == null ? null : Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.