# How to route a ulong to an ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently building a project that deals with Discord users. For those who don't know, each Discord user has a unique Id, stored as `ulong`.

I am trying to route this Id to my page (currently looks like this)

```
@page "{UserId:ulong?}"
@model BotFrameworkInterface.Pages.Bot.UserDetailsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserDetails";
}

<h1>UserDetails</h1>

@foreach(var u in Model.SelectedUsers)
{
    <Partial name="_Summary" model="u"/>
}
```

but it breaks and gives me the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'ulong' could not
>   be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.

is there any way I can pass in a `ulong` into my ASP.NET (core) page? (the partial view works fine, I checked it)

Comment: You could use a regex, or create your own mapper. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922418/the-constraint-reference-slugify-could-not-be-resolved-to-a-type, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-routing-constraint/.

Comment: I would honestly rather pass it in as a string... since it's just 1 variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ulong`  data type is not included in the applicable routing constraints , reference: [Route constraint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-constraint-reference)

If you want to check the id by Route constraint, you could implement your own constraint by implementing IRouteConstraint.

1.UlongRouteConstraint

```
 public class UlongRouteConstraint: IRouteConstraint
{
    public static string UlongRouteConstraintName = "UlongConstraint";
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object dateValue;
        if (values.TryGetValue("id", out dateValue))
        {
            ulong date;
            if (UInt64.TryParse(dateValue.ToString(), out date))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

2.Register UlongRouteConstraint

```
 services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConstraintMap.Add(UlongRouteConstraint.UlongRouteConstraintName, typeof(UlongRouteConstraint));
        });
```

3.Use Case

```
@page "{id:UlongConstraint?}"
@model RazorPages2_2Test.Pages.Users.DetailsModel
```

Comment: I'll try to implement that, I basically did the same check with tryparse, only in my OnGet function. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

without "id" param hardcode :)

```
public class UlongRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public static string UlongRouteConstraintName = "ulong";

    public bool Match(HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(routeKey));

        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

        if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var routeValue) || routeValue == null) return false;
        if (routeValue is ulong)
            return true;

        var valueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return ulong.TryParse(valueString, out var _);
    }
}
```